# for loop in C ;for(conditions); a command;

Tags: c, for-loop

How does this for loop work?

```
for (i = 0; N[i] != 0 && N[i] != '.'; i++);N[i] = 0;printf("%s", N);
```

Input: N = 123456.789 (char)

Out: 123456

To be specific, what I know about for loop is

1. `for(i=0;i<10;i++){sentences}`
2. `for(i=0;i<10;i++) a sentence;`

How this for loop is working?

Comment: First try to reformat the code so you know which parts are inside the loop and which are not (good code-oriented text editors can do that for you automatically). Then use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Finally, remember that the string terminator, commonly called the null or NUL terminator, is equal to the integer value zero.

Comment: I see there is a `;` after the loop statement.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of writing it on a single line, where it's unreadable, split it out (and using `'\0'` instead of `0` for a character, for clarity):

```
for (i = 0; N[i] != '\0' && N[i] != '.'; i++)
    ; // Empty loop
N[i] = '\0';
printf("%s", N);
```

This increments the index `i` until the character in the string `N` is a `'.'`, or until you reach the end of the string.

It then replaces the character at index `i` with a NUL string terminator (you code had that written as `0`, which is fine, but I find `'\0'` shows intent more clearly). If this was already the end of the string this does nothing. If it was a `'.'`, this truncates the string at the period.

It then prints this truncated string, without the period that it removed.

Comment: ...without a period _and everything that might have followed the perid_, like a filename extension, for example.

Comment: @CiaPan I say that it prints the truncated string. That part about the period is just to make it clear that what's printed is exclusive of the period, as opposed to printing everything up to and including it.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 0; N[i] != 0 && N[i] != '.'; i++);N[i] = 0;printf("%s", N);
```

Is equal to

```
for (i = 0; N[i] != 0 && N[i] != '.';i++) {
}
N[i] = 0;
printf("%s", N);
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop

```
for (init_expression; cond_expression; incr_expression)
    instr;
```

is equivalent to

```
init_expression;
while (cond_expression)
{
    instr;
    incr_expression;
}
```

So your loop `for (i = 0; N[i] != 0 && N[i] != '.'; i++);` is

```
i = 0;
while (N[i] != 0 && N[i] != '.')
{
    ;
    i++;
}
```

In words, it sets `i` to `0` first, which is an index of the first character in the `N` string.
Then it test if the `i`-th charater in the string `N` is not zero (which means the string is not exhausted yet, as a zero byte is the string terminator) and not a dot. If that appears true, the index variable `i` gets incremented and the loop continues.

In other words, the loop scans the string till its end or the first dot encountered, in which case the loop terminates.

So you find a first dot or a string's end. Then the zero character is put at the position found. As a result the string gets truncated at the first dot's position (or remains unchanged if there were no dots in it).

Answer (score -1):

Indentation does not change the semantics, but it makes the code easier to read.  You code is equivalent to:

```
for (i = 0; N[i] != 0 && N[i] != '.'; i++)
    /* A no-op */;
N[i] = 0;
printf("%s", N);
```

Comment: no, it is not, this answer has 'skipped' the semicolon `;` at the end of the `for()` statement.

Comment: @user3629249 No, the semi-colon is simply placed afer a new-line and a comment.